# Test if the theory fits the data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

We are given that the members of a community are classified by blood type according to the following schema:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
O& A & B & AB & Total \\ \hline
121 & 120 & 79 & 33 & 353\\ \hline
\end{array}

We are also given that the probabilities of the above blood types depend on gene frequency parameters $r, p, q$ satisfying the following relations:

$$
r + p + q = 1
$$
$$
P(\text{O}) = r^2
$$
$$
P(\text{A}) = p^2 + 2pr
$$
$$
P(\text{B}) = q^2 + 2qr
$$
$$
P(\text{AB}) = 2pq
$$
Finally, we are given the MLEs of the $p,q, r$, which are:
$$
\hat{r} = 0.580
$$
$$
\hat{p} = 0.246
$$
$$
\hat{q} = 0.173
$$
My question is, what is the approach to testing if the given community fits the theory. Typically the approach is to use a $\chi^2$ test for goodness of fit but I cannot see how it would apply in this scenario. Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
It was brought to my attention that I am not exactly stating what aspect of the test I am not understanding. Here is that information:

1. I am assuming that $H_1$ in this case will be that the proposed theory fits the data and $H_0$ that it does not.
2. There does not seem to be a preferred level of significance so I goes 5% should be acceptable (if there is motivation to choose a different one, please let me know)
3. The degrees of freedom will be 3(?)
4. For expected frequencies I should have e.g. $0 \times P(\text{0}) = 121 \times 0.580^2 $ and so on.
5. The observed data is given and the test statistic is easy to compute.

Is the summary I have provided the way to tackle this or am I missing some aspect of the problem?

**UPDATE 2**:
It was mentioned to me that the degrees of freedom should be less than 3 because of the MLEs. It is not clear to me how this happens exactly. Could someone elaborate on this aspect of the problem?

**FINAL UPDATE**:
I think that considering the comments in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200862/does-the-theory-fit-the-given-data) and my sketch of the approach suffices to solve the problem. My thanks to everyone who offered their expertise!

Comment: I'm not sure if I can answer your question, but my limited experience leads me to suspectthat $H_0$ and $H_1$ are swapped. Usually the $H_1$ amounts to "my theory" and $H_0$ amounts to "some other theory is right," (i.e. "my theory is wrong") which is an important distinction because $H_0$ still leaves lots of possibilities available

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for this observation!

Comment: This 'reversal' is often the case with goodness-of-fit tests. That makes it important to consider the power of the GOF test: What is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is objectionably far from being true. Often, this requires a simulation study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your null hypothesis is that Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium has been
reached for blood types in the population in which the blood
samples were drawn.

You have observed counts $\#O = 121,\,$ $\#A = 120,\,$ $\#B = 79,\,$ and $\#AB = 33.$ At equilibrium, the probabilities are
as shown in your question and the expected counts are derived
using the MLEs:

The respective expected counts are 
$E_O = n\hat r^2 = 353*(.580)^2 = 118.7492\,$
$E_A = n(\hat p^2 + 2\hat p \hat r) = 353(.246^2 + 2(.246)(.580)) = 122.0942\,$
$E_B = n(\hat q^2 + 2\hat q \hat r) = 353(.173^2 + 2(.173)(.580)) = 81.4050\,$
and $E_{AB} = n(2 \hat p \hat q) = 353(2(.245)(.173)) =  29.9238.$

As a check we verify that the expected counts also sum to 353 (within rounding error): $118.7492+122.0942+81.4050+29.9238 =  352.1722.$

The ch-squared goodness-of-fit statistic is
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{(X_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}.$$
Where the observed counts are designated $X_i$.

Using R, we find that $Q =  0.4659$.

```
 obs = c(121, 120, 79, 33)
 exp = c(118.7492, 122.0942, 81.4050, 29.9238)
 q = sum((obs - exp)^2/exp); q
 ## 0.4658718
```

Under the null hypothesis the approximate distribution of 
$Q$ is $Q \sim Chisq(df = 1).$ The rationale for having
only one degree of freedom is that the MLEs are based on
estimating the proportion of A and B alleles in the population.
Without estimation we would have had $df = 4-1 = 3,$ but
we lose a degree of freedom for each quantity directly estimated.

The P-value of the test is the probability $0.495$
under the $Chisq(1)$
density curve to the right of $0.4659$. Thus the agreement
of observed counts with expected counts is good enough to be
considered consistent with equilibrium.

Below is a plot of the PDF of $Chisq(1)$ with a vertical dotted
line at the observed value of the GOF statistic. (This is a 
'heavy-tailed' distribution with more probability towards
higher values than may be apparent from the plot.)

[image]

Comment: The perfect answer! Includes everything necessary!